# different page numbering formats and GOTO in pdf files

Tags: pdf, microsoft-word, adobe-acrobat

I have a question concerning creating professional PDF files. Let's consider the following description of some document:

- ***first 3 pages*** : not numbered
- ***pages 4-10*** : numbered i,ii,iii,iv,v,vi.
- ***pages 11-end***: numbered 1,2,...

Now this document is something I can create in Microsoft Word easily, and CTRL-G (*go to some page*) would work if I type any number (i,ii...vi) or (1,2...) and it would take me to the appropriate page. But when I generate a pdf file, this feature doesn't work; if I try to go to page iv for example it would say there's no page numbered 'iv' in the document as all the pages are numbered 1,2,3 starting from the first page to the last page.

I know that what I'm trying to achieve *is* possible as I've seen a while back a PDF book having this feature and I was wondering how could I do the same.

Hopefully my question is clear enough; thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you saying that you have a document of this kind in MS Word, but that when you render to PDF the internal hyperlinks are broken? What reader are you using?

Comment: Ah - I see the problem. If you have an contents page, it will probably label pages correctly (e.g. i, ii, a, b, 1, 2 etc) but you are using the Goto feature of the reader. That doesn't understand special numerals afaik - it _only_ understands numbers. Hence if you go to page 4, you will end up going to page (i), since this is the forth page. If you believe you've seen a PDF in which this is possible, can you supply an example, or cite something on the web? It is possible this feature exists, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: thanks for the reply, what i mean is this box in the pdf reader : http://free-picture-hosting.net/?dm=MPVH

Comment: yep exactly as you described, unfortunatly for the pdf, i don't really remember in which one i've found it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, a quick search reveals [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/PDF17.html). There are some notes there that might give you some clues in the right direction: there is a PDF entity called */PageLabels* which you'll need to research.

Lastly I found [this commercial software](http://www.a-pdf.com/number-pro/) that claims to do what you ask. I've no idea if it works, mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Adobe Acrobat Pro, you can change this.
View the page thumbnails for your document. You can right-click one of the thumbnails and then click "Number Pages...". This opens a dialog box where you can change the page numbering.